# Binary Tree Traversal (Reverse Preorder)

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree

I want to have a vector that pushes in 'R' everytime the tree traverses to the right subtree and pushes in 'L' everytime the tree traverse to a left subtree.

```
void reverse_preorder(BTree<string>* root)
{ vector<string>a;
    if (root != NULL) {
        a.push_back("R");
        if(root->right == NULL) a.push_back("L");
        reverse_preorder(root->right);
        reverse_preorder(root->left);
    }
}
```

but for some reason the output im getting is not in the correct order. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First of all if you want to keep your results when returning from your recursive calls you should pass your vector along as an argument.

Comment: Seems like you are pushing to "R" at every iteration and you are only pushing to "L" when you don't have a Right Child

Comment: Please provide us the real code. The code here is clearly not showing everithing. You are pushing to `a`, but you don't use it for anything later, for example.

Comment: So far this is what I have, I haven't yet coded what im going to use a for later, i'm first testing to see if I can even get the right set of elements into a so I can use it

Comment: As written each vector (there will be one per call, So N-recurses will result in N vectors) will never have more than two strings.. I hope you realize that.

Comment: Oh I see, so maybe I should make a vector function and insert it into the traversal

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: I want to traverse the tree in a reverse preorder form (Node,Right,Left) while im traversing through the tree I want to push "R" if it is at a right subtree and "L" if its at a left subtree. Then when I'm done with that I'll use the vector as a guide to print out the tree in a "pretty" format @evhen14

Answer (score 0):

Make the vector a member of your class. Then

```
void reverse_preorder(BTree<string>* root)
{
    if (root != NULL) {
        if (root->right != NULL) a.push_back("R");
        reverse_preorder(root->right);
        if (root->left != NULL) a.push_back("L");
        reverse_preorder(root->left);
    }
}
```

Though, I don't see how it will help you to do a 'pretty' formatting.